# ConcurrentDictionary fails to find a key even if I am sure it exists

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, stream, concurrentdictionary

In my static class I have this:

```
static var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
```

In thread #1 I do this:

```
cache.TryAdd (stringFromSomewhere, newlyCreatedObject); 
Console.WriteLine(stringFromSomewhere); // Outputs "abc"
```

**Couple of seconds after Thread #1**, in Thread #2:

```
if(cache.ContainsKey(stringFromSomewhereElse))
    Console.WriteLine("Yes, it exists.");
else
    Console.WriteLine("This did not exist: " + stringFromSomewhereElse);
```

It outputs "This did not exist: abc"

Then in Thread #3 couple of seconds after the Thread #2:

```
foreach(var kvp in cache)
{
    Console.WriteLine("string: " + kvp.Key);
    if(cache.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        Console.WriteLine("Yes, it exists.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("This did not exist: " + kvp.Key);
}
```

I get the output "string: abc" and "Yes, it exists."

In Thread #1 I create the string using MD5 like this:

```
Convert.ToBase64String (md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value)))
```

And in Thread #2 I get the string from a byte stream, where the string was written to using UTF8 Encoding, and then read to string from bytes using UTF8 Encoding again.

In thread #3 I get the string by looping through the ConcurrentDictionary.

What am I missing here? To the best of my knowledge, Thread #2 should behave just like Thread #3 does.

I have two possibilities, which both are in my opinion long shots:

- Is this some kind of synchronizing problem I am not aware of?
- Or is the string different somehow? When I output it to the console, it does not differ.

Anyone got any other ideas, or solutions?

**EDIT:**

I write the data to the stream like this:

```
string data = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(theString);
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (data);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); // TcpClient client;
stream.Write (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Then I read the data from the stream like this:

```
string data = "";
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); // TcpClient client;
byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
do {   
    int i = stream.Read (bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString (bytes, 0, i);
} while(stream.DataAvailable);
string theString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data);
```

Comment: You must provide more code.

Comment: What do you want to see?

Comment: The minimal code snippet which behaves as described.

Comment: I added edit where I describe how I write the string to the stream and read it back.

Comment: Maybe you can show the code where you work with cache?

Comment: That is really all the code that gets executed when I am accessing the cache. I added the foreach loop in the Thread #3. I have a strong feeling that I am going to facepalm quite a lot after I get to correct this.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the stream?

Comment: I do not see what good that would do, since it obviously gets sent to the client via the tcpclient, which returns the data and I am able to fetch it. To be more clear: Thread #1 sends the data thru the stream, Thread #2 recieves the data from the stream when the client sends it. When outputting the string to console, I verify that it is identical to the string I sent.

Comment: When you output it to the console, output the length and put quotes around the string. Sounds like there might be some spaces or non-printable characters. Something like `Console.WriteLine("This did not exist: '{0}', Length={1}", stringFromSomewhereElse, stringFromSomewhereElse.Length);`

Comment: @JimMischel Thank you. There indeed seems to be \r at the end of the string I get from the stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing bytes to a network stream and then reading them back, you have to either precede the data with a value that says how many bytes follow, or you need an end-of-data marker. The way your code is written, it's quite possible that the receive code is only picking up part of the data.

Imagine, for example, that your key is "HelloWorld". Your send code sends the string out. The receive code sees the "Hello" part in the buffer, grabs it, checks to see if more data is available, and it's not because the network transport thread hasn't finished copying it to the buffer.

So you get only part of the string.

Another thing that can happen is that you read too much. That can happen if you write two strings out to the network stream and your reader reads both of them as if they're a single string.

To do it right, you should do either this:

```
int dataLength = buffer.Length;
byte[] lengthBuff = BitConverter.GetBytes(dataLength);
stream.Write(lengthBuff, 0, lengthBuff.Length);  // write length
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);  // write data
```

And then read it by first reading the length and then reading that many bytes from the stream.

Or, you can use an end-of-data marker:

```
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);  // write data
buffer[0] = end_of_data_byte;
stream.Write(buffer, 0, 1);  // write end of data
```

And your reader reads bytes until it gets the end of data marker.

What you use for an end of data marker is up to you. It should be something that won't be in the normal data stream.

Personally, I'd go for the length prefix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand this concept, but it's not really solving the issue here. When I get the data from the stream in Thread #2 and pass it to the static class to find out if the key exists, it says that it does not exist, but still outputs the correct string as shown in the explanation of the problem.

Comment: Also I may have oversimplified the reading process from the stream. I actually read quite a lot of data (but less than 4kb) and parse out the string from the text data using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand the flow of your question - however one thing I notice: do you Flush() after the network Write()? Otherwise you can get delays in the write, which in general can cause timing related issues.